# Calculate all the possible combinations from a given sequence (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, combinatorics, biopython

I have the following dictionary which contains all the possible codons (values|triplets) per amino acids (keys|letters). This dictionary is also known as the 'DNA codon table' in Bioinformatics.

```
codon_table = {
'A': ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
'C': ('TGT', 'TGC'),
'D': ('GAT', 'GAC'),
'E': ('GAA', 'GAG'),
'F': ('TTT', 'TTC'),
'G': ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
'H': ('CAT', 'CAC'),
'I': ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
'K': ('AAA', 'AAG'),
'L': ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
'M': ('ATG',),
'N': ('AAT', 'AAC'),
'P': ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
'Q': ('CAA', 'CAG'),
'R': ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
'S': ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'),
'T': ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
'V': ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
'W': ('TGG',),
'Y': ('TAT', 'TAC'),}
```

I would like to create all the possible combinations of triplets for a given sequence of 'keys'. 
For instance the **FMW** sequence should have the following two results:
*TTTATGTGG* and *TTCATGTGG*. The number of combinations should be the product of the number of values of each key in the dictionary. In our case for the **FMW** should be 2*1*1 = 2 combinations.

Which is the most pythonic and efficient way to do such calculations for sequences of 10 (and more) letters? Is there an already implemented method in any Biopython package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `seq` here is the list of keys that you have. If you have it in any other form (like a `string`) it can easily be treated as a `char` array and broken down into the `seq` list. Once you do that, `itertools` does a wonderful job doing *exactly* what you want. Here is the full code -

```
import itertools
codon_table = {
'A': ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
'C': ('TGT', 'TGC'),
'D': ('GAT', 'GAC'),
'E': ('GAA', 'GAG'),
'F': ('TTT', 'TTC'),
'G': ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
'H': ('CAT', 'CAC'),
'I': ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
'K': ('AAA', 'AAG'),
'L': ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
'M': ('ATG',),
'N': ('AAT', 'AAC'),
'P': ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
'Q': ('CAA', 'CAG'),
'R': ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
'S': ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'),
'T': ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
'V': ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
'W': ('TGG',),
'Y': ('TAT', 'TAC'),}

seq = ['F', 'M', 'W']
t1, t2, t3 = [ list(codon_table[key]) for key in seq ]
print(list(itertools.product(t1, t2, t3)))
```

**Output**

```
[('TTT', 'ATG', 'TGG'), ('TTC', 'ATG', 'TGG')]
```

**OP Output**

Further, if you want the output exactly as you wanted, instead of the last print statement, you can go for -

```
output = list(itertools.product(t1, t2, t3))
print(output)

output_flat = [ ''.join(a) for a in output ]
print(output_flat)
```

This outputs -

```
['TTTATGTGG', 'TTCATGTGG']
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: You should omit the step, where you unpack the `codon_table` values into three temporary `t` variables. Instead unpack directly for `itertools.product` like `print(list(itertools.product(*[list(codon_table[key]) for key in seq])))`. This makes it more flexible, how many elements seq can contain.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly less related to your question, but here's an expanded codon chart in regex format. Figured it could be helpful, as it allows ambiguous matches (both nucleotide and amino acid). It will also significantly reduce the amount of output. Note - unable to post as comment due to length.

```
codon_table = {
'A':['[GRSK][CYSM].'],
'B':['[ARWM][ARWM][CTYWKSM]', '[GRSK][ARWM][TCYWKSM]'],
'C':['[TYWK][GRSK][TCYWKSM]'],
'D':['[GRSK][ARWM][TCYWKSM]'],
'E':['[GRSK][ARWM][AGRSKWM]'],
'F':['[TYWK][TYWK][CTYWKSM]'],
'G':['[GRSK][GRSK].'],
'H':['[CYSM][ARWM][TCYWKSM]'],
'I':['[ARWM][TYWK][^G]'],
'J':['[ARWM][TYWK][^G]', '[CYSM][TYWK].', '[TYWK][TYWK][AGRSKWM]'],
'K':['[ARWM][ARWM][AGRSKWM]'],
'L':['[CYSM][TYWK].', '[TYWK][TYWK][AGRSKWM]'],
'M':['[ARWM][TYWK][GRSK]'],
'N':['[ARWM][ARWM][CTYWKSM]'],
'O':['[TYWK][ARWM][GRSK]'],
'P':['[CYSM][CYSM].'],
'Q':['[CYSM][ARWM][AGRSKWM]'],
'R':['[CYSM][GRSK].', '[ARWM][GRSK][GARSKWM]'],
'S':['[TYWK][CYSM].', '[ARWM][GRSK][CTYWKSM]'],
'T':['[ARWM][CYSM].'],
'U':['[TYWK][GRSK][ARWM]'],
'V':['[GRSK][TYWK].'],
'W':['[TYWK][GRSK][GRSK]'],
'X':['...'],
'Y':['[TYWK][ARWM][CTYWKSM]'],
'Z':['[CYSM][ARWM][AGRSKWM]','[GRSK][ARWM][AGRSKWM]'],
'_':['[TYWK][ARWM][AGRSKWM]', '[TYWK][GRSK][ARWM]'],
'*':['[TYWK][ARWM][AGRSKWM]', '[TYWK][GRSK][ARWM]']}
```

Comment: I do not exactly understand what's the purpose of this code by saying ambitious matches, what exactly do and how this dictionary could be found useful. Could you please explain in more detail? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. When DNA is being sequenced, the residue at a given position might not be well identified. For example, if there is equal signal for cytosine and thymine, a sequencer would record "Y", indicating the position is a pyrimidine (C or T). Similarly, amino acids can be ambiguous. A residue that is either asparagine or aspartic acid is represented by the letter "B". By including characters indicating ambiguity, you improve your odds of matching imperfect (biologically relevant) sequences.

Comment: Sources: http://www.dnabaser.com/articles/IUPAC%20ambiguity%20codes.html and http://wiki.thegpm.org/wiki/Amino_acid_symbols